# Kafka java producer and consumer with ACL enabled with topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm bit confused with kafka ACL configuration, where we configure authorization for producer and consumer.
There are various examples showing producing/consuming message using command line.
Do we need any extra configuration to produce/consume messages using JAVA api to/from secured kafka topic.

Comment: did you find any response about ACL with java producer ?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to learn about the details of configuration for a secured Kafka server, [Confluent docs](http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/kafka/security.html) has an excellent description. You can notice in the docs that you set certain properties through a file *client.properties*, which shall be used as a config file for the console producer and consumer. Similarly in the case of Java consumer/producer, you can set these properties as described in the examples [here](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html).

Answer (score -1):

@Apollo : This question is quite vague.. If you want to learn ACL/ SSL it will take some time.. the below link might help you to get started. 
https://github.com/Symantec/kafka-security-0.9